# Why AudioBufferSourceNodes stacks on play?

Tags: javascript, audio, streaming, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

Basicly, I'm trying to build and play audio data from bytes, that comes from WS sockets.

Detailed:

---

I have simple WS server written in Django-Channels, that on connect returns me splitted audio file in blob object with 6144 bytes of each chunk. Next, I want to decode this blob data and turn it into sound:

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source;
var play = document.querySelector('#play');
var audioQueue = []

const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    'ws://'
    + window.location.host
    + 'audio-stream-test'
    + '/'
);

chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
    e.data.arrayBuffer().then(buffer => {
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(buffer, (x)=>{
            source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = x;
            source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
            source.loop = false;
            audioQueue.push(source)
        })
    })
}
```

After WS sent all the data, it closes on server side. The last thing is to play queued buffers from `audioQueue` array:

```
play.onclick = function() {
    var playOffset;
    for (let [bufferCount, buffer] of audioQueue.entries()) {
        if (bufferCount == 0) {
            playOffset = 0
        } else {
            playOffset = audioQueue[bufferCount-1].buffer.duration
        }
        buffer.start(when=playOffset)
    }
}
```

Want to clarify about this line: `playOffset = audioQueue[bufferCount-1].buffer.duration`. I think, i'm writed it right because I want to play new buffer at the end of old (already played) one.

For me, as *server-side* developer, it seems like it should work fine.

---

But, the main problem is: all buffers from `audioQueue` array is played **at once**. IDK what I'm doing wrong. Hoping for youre help :)

---

[The song](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VWk83AAG76ibGWQwIH6WxgCo1BOjN2v6/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start each `AudioBufferSourceNode` in relation to the `currentTime` of the `AudioContext`.

```
play.onclick = function() {
    audioQueue.reduce((startTime, audioBufferSourceNode) => {
        audioBufferSourceNode.start(startTime);

        return startTime + audioBufferSourceNode.buffer.duration;
    }, audioContext.currentTime);
};
```

The code above will loop through all nodes in the `audioQueue`. It computes the `startTime` for each `AudioBufferSourceNode` by accumulating the durations of the previous nodes based on the `currentTime` of the `AudioContext`.